# c# how to completely disable a user button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# application with a form window that has a button on it, I'll call `myButton`. I have an event attached to it, `myButton_Click`. What I want to do is disable the button and not allow any user interface with the button while the actions within the `myButton_Click` method are running.

Currently I launch another executable from within the `myButton_Click` method and like I said I do NOT want any user interaction while the other application is running. The problem I am running into is that even though the button is disabled, by `myButton.Enabled == false;`, if I click multiple times on the disabled button once I close the running application that was launched from within '`myButton_Click`', the method '`myButton_Click`' gets recalled as many times as I clicked on the disabled button previously.

In short I would like a way to make sure that no actions/button clicks are stored/accumulated while the outside application is running on the button that I disabled.

E.g.

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       myButton.Enabled = false;
       ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = "someapplication.EXE";

            try
            {
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch{// Log error.   
            }

        myButton.Enabled = true;// turn the button back on
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try myButton.Visible = false;

Comment: An alternative might be to check if the application is running already and ignore button clicks if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI thread is being blocked by your external EXE and it's queuing up those click events.  The proper solution is to use a background worker like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (doWorkSender, doWorkArgs) =>
    {
        // You will want to call your external app here...
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (completedSender, completedArgs) =>
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think using async/await can give a cleaner solution

```
async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    await RunProcessAsync("notepad.exe");
    button1.Enabled = true;
}


public Task RunProcessAsync(string processName)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = processName;
    var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.Exited += (s,e) => tcs.TrySetResult(null);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I have access to TaskCompletionSource, I'm using 3.5 net.

Comment: @67vette427 You see now why a good *tagging* of the question is necessary (*visual-studio* is not related since even with notepad you could do what you have done so far)

Comment: What? Understand about good tagging but was does notepad have to do with C#?

Comment: @67vette427 You can even write your code without using VS. Notepad + csc is enough.

Comment: OK you can write it in notepad then how do you compile it?

Comment: @67vette427 **csc**, C# command line compiler. `...\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe`

Comment: But that is not how I am developing my application I'm using in Visual studio thusly the tag.

Comment: @67 there is also a tag `Keyboard`, why haven't you use it? Don't you use keyboard while writing code :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you're even getting that problem. It could possibly be that the windows message is not disabling the button quick enough.  You could try putting a `DoEvents()` instruction after `myButton.Enabled = false;`

Comment: And this also worked. But the DoEvents had to go after coming out of the exeProcess.WaitForExit().